# Would organisms genetically descendent from humans fall under the purview of the Catholic defined God?

Tags: catholicism, transhumanism

Scientists are discussing the theoretical possibility of transferring human bacteria to other planets as a way of encouraging a genetically descendent human species - primarily in places such as Mars.  It's proposed as one tactic to "continue" the human race.

"If you want to roll with the terraforming scenario a bit further, you can imagine the human-encoded bacteria reassembles naturally, through organic processes, to eventually evolve into descendant organisms—sort of restarting the human population."

http://motherboard.vice.com/read/our-best-bet-for-colonizing-space-may-be-printing-humans-on-other-planets

Would a human-initiated reboot of a genetically descendent population, such as this, still fall under the purview of a Christian "God" or would such beings not count as "humans", thus not required to obey a "God" much the same way as animals are not required.

Comment: If you want to close it, I'm curious to know why.  Feel free to comment.

Comment: I think you will run in to the same problem as your other post tagged with transhumanism - the scope of providing a "Christian" answer is too broad for the specific focussed Q&A format of this site - there can be no correct answer to your question.  Try editing it to limit the scope to a particular tradition - eg. tag Catholic & ask "Would the Catholic conception of the soul etc." or tag Calvinist/Evangelical/Some other flavor of Protestant ("Would the <Insert Protestant tradition X> understanding of scripture... etc.?"

Comment: If you would like multiple viewpoints, you can ask a new question for each viewpoint you seek an answer from

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no 'Christian' answer to this question, and that no Christian group has considered it enough to have a definite opinion. It's a fascinating discussion question, but not really suitable for this site.

Comment: Perhaps I'm optimistic that there IS a Christian perspective.  I think some of you are too quick assume there isn't.  If there isn't, then I call on Christianity to catch up.

However I would agree that I can specify a group instead.

Comment: I changed my question to address the Catholic perspective.

Comment: @rpeg I would like to question your focus on the Catholic perspective. You initially wanted to seek a "Christian" perspective on the matter, and then once you noticed that a single Christian opinion cannot be settled, you decided to narrow down, seemingly randomly, to "Catholicism". Do you have any justification for your focus on Catholicism?

Comment: I am afraid the question is too much of a hypothetical. It's like asking, "What does the Catholic Church say about the Flying Spaghetti Monster?"

Comment: My interest is to find out as many Christian perspectives as possible and so I decided to start with Catholicism.

Comment: Also, "What does the Catholic Church say about the Flying Spaghetti Monster?" is not a hypothetical. If it was posited as, "hypothetically speaking, IF a flying spaghetti monster existed, what would be the Catholic perspective".  That's a hypothetical.  My question is more about Catholicism's opinion on evolution in relation to semi-human lifeforms, whether or not they come into existence.  I'm not proposing any hypothetical assumptions.  You can believe it's impossible but still hold a theological opinion.

Comment: @rpeg You do understand that a single Catholic's opinion on this subject may be different from the Vatican's point of view, right?

Comment: @Anonymous Do you know there are 30k Christian sects with varying opinions on everything?  Yes, I know the Vatican's opinion may be different. That's part of the flaw in the concept of this website.  Everything is opinion.  How else do you suggest a frame this question towards the Catholic perspective?

Comment: @Anonymous Catholicsim has a defined set of dogmas some of which are relevant to the discussion of the issue (nature of the soul, God's creation etc.) It's not unreasonable to expect an answer from their perspective.

Comment: I think it's more likely that Catholicism would have an answer than other denominations. See for example [this answer](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/28350/6071).

Comment: @bruisedreed We actually _don't_ really want to see questions repeated one-per-perspective if we can help it. That cookie cutter approach just makes a mess. On the other hand most questions need more scoping than they are usually given, but that should force the OP to narrow down what they actually want to learn, not force them to pigeon hole their question with a hack.

Comment: As @Anonymous noted, the Catholicism thing seems like a hack job on here. I suggest either asking a question that is actually about Catholicism or fixing this so it's workable as an overview question. I think I can make this work as the latter if you're amenable.

Comment: @Caleb I've heard the opposite elsewhere on the site where it was insisted that specificity be offered.

Comment: How is the question not about Catholicism and what defines a "hack job"?

Comment: @rpeg 99 times out of 100 more specificity is better, but there are times when it just doesn't make sense. I think this is one and that suggestions to the contrary are the result of blanket applying a rule without working through the implications to the specific case.

Comment: If the persons here can't agree upon the idea of a broad Christian perspective and want to narrow the viewpoint, it seems to make perfect sense that I may inquire the perspective of a major institution like Catholicism.

Comment: @Caleb he already tried a non-specific question in this area and it was closed as off-topic - should it have been? Perhaps a little more guidance towards making it an acceptable overview question is in order

Comment: I want to defend this question as I believe it's VERY possible that someone or even some niche christian community, has a perspective.

Comment: @Caleb the difficulty in getting a proper overview answer to a question like this is that the respondant will need a degree of expertise in most or all of the relevant doctrines for a representative range of traditions. I'm not saying it's not possible that someone has that level of knowledge, but I imagine there would at best be only a very limited number of users who could do that properly.

Comment: @rpeg I attempted to demonstrate by an example answer how I think this can be treated [as an overview question](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/871/30). To that end I edited the Catholic bit I don't think  makes sense here out. For whatever reason you stuck it back in, rendering the wording of my answer out of place. Is there any reason you actually want specifically the Vatican and only the Vatican's statement on this? Your previous comments led me to believe that is not what you were after. The gist is the same, but tho answer would need to be framed differently.

Comment: "For whatever reason you stuck it back in" I felt it was a better question focusing on Catholicism.  It seems as though you changed it to make it easier for you to answer.

Comment: It's a shame this question is getting flagged as I think it better deals with the essence of "humanity" and deep questions we will have in the future.

Comment: Please don't down-vote because you're simply biased.

Comment: @rpeg If "biased" means "favoring the ideal of this website", then yes, we are biased in that sense. What's cool about the SE is that it allows people to retract their downvotes. If you improve this question so that it implies a *reason* for asking about the Vatican's opinion, then it may be upvoted, or at least the downvotes may be removed by the same individuals.

Comment: Eyeroll @Anonymous

Answer (score 4):

This idea of propagating the human 'race' through bacteria of other DNA carriers is relatively new even to the fields of science and philosophy and is premised on a very secular humanist world view with it's own existential definitions of things. I do not think *any* major Christian group<sup>1</sup> currently has doctrinal statements that speak directly to the issue using the same terminology; although that is likely to change in the near future. Most issues raised in the secular world that have spiritual implications are eventually addressed specifically, but usually this is done in response to confusion or errant doctrine. Rarely is it done preemptively.

That being said, it is also not any stretch of the imagination to extrapolate from well established principals and suggest what Christianity's position on this is in general terms.

1. In Christianity across a wide swath of theological spectrums, *EVERYTHING* is seen as falling under the purview of God. Certainly none of the major branches of Christianity would disagree with this and off the top of my head I cannot even think of any sects that take a radically different view. This is clearly expressed not only in Scripture but in many creeds. For example even in passing, mentions of God often identify him as the God of everything in all of creation.

   > **[Acts 17:24a](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+17%3A24&version=ESV)** (ESV)
   >   <sup>24</sup>  The God who made the world and everything in it, being Lord of heaven and earth, […]

   In other words it does not matter what matter you ask, how it is tinkered with in a laboratory, or where it is located, it will be the preview of God. Another expression of this that shows the all-encompassing nature of creation as God's is given in Colossians in relation to  Christ (interpretation of this varies in some sects, but the gist of the idea that *all creation*, not just parts of it belong to God is pretty constant).

   > **[Colossians 1:16-17](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Colossians+1%3A16-17&version=ESV)** (ESV)
   >   <sup>16</sup>  For by him all things were created, in heaven and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or authorities—all things were created through him and for him. <sup>17</sup>  And he is before all things, and in him all things hold together.
2. In spite of specific differences in understanding (e.g. bipartite vs. tripartite nature of man, the extent of 'sin nature', etc.) Christianity almost universally recognizes some basic attributes of man that make him human. How there are expressed has adapted to our scientific understanding, but the basics remain unchanged. In some specific attributes humans are distinct from other created beings. It is not the fact that we are a living organism that makes us human, it is the fact that we have certain properties. In official doctrinal statements this will be variously identified as "having a soul" or "being able to reason", but they all stem from man having been made "in the image of God".

   > **[Genesis 1:26](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+1:26&version=ESV)** (ESV)
   >   <sup>26</sup>  Then God said, “Let us make man in our image, after our likeness. And let them have dominion over the fish of the sea and over the birds of the heavens and over the livestock and over all the earth and over every creeping thing that creeps on the earth.”

   This distinction is not made for the creation of other species of animals and I know of no Christian sects that do not recognize at least some basic distinction along these lines.

From those two basic Christian beliefs in can easily be extrapolated that:

- Christianity does not (neither historically nor currently) label anything as human that does not fit the classic understanding of such. No bacteria or disembodied tissue—whatever DNA may be present—is considered a substitute for the combination of body and soul that comprises humanity.
- Under no circumstances, no matter what science comes up with to advance or pervert creation, will any part of the physical universe be outside the the rightful dominion of God. Historically even attempts to *suggest* otherwise have met with God's blunt denial that such a thing will be (see for example the Tower of Babel episode).

<sub><sup>1</sup> A notable exception might be "Christian Scientology", although to my knowledge the branches that have significantly different doctrinal views on issues like this also don't claim affiliation with Christianity in a way that would make them relevant to the scope of the question.</sub>

Comment: Great response.

Comment: There are Christians who do not believe in evolution that must be excluded from your answer as it is based on the assumption that Darwinian evolution exists. You cannot make a statement for most Christians unless you can prove that most Christians believe in unscientific evolution theories. There are also Christians who realize that the science the question is based on is complete nonsense and that the question should have been placed on hold immediately as it is intended as a provocation.

Comment: Maybe just answer for the Catholics.

Comment: @gideonmarx Just because a (significant) number of Christian perspectives would reject that particular premise in the OP, doesn't mean they can't speak to the issue in a hypothetical fashion - in fact for anyone to address it, they must do likewise as it is a hypothetical question.

Comment: @gideonmarx Caleb's answer doesn't rely on that premise (it neither explicitly denies it nor affirms it) so it is well crafted to serve multiple viewpoints.

Comment: Honestly this is answer is so well crafted that I don't agree (nor understanding) the down-voting of the question. This answer affirms that the question CAN be answered and can be as informative as the answer.

Comment: @gideon Your objection is absolutely baffeling to me because I am an adament creationist myself that totally rejets Darwinian evolution. If anything this answer would hinge on that premise as it identifies God as creator. Yet still I don't think the issue hinges on that for Christians from either school of thought.

Comment: @Caleb. The question is based on the assumption that evolution exists (in a highly unscientific form) and if you answer you argue from that point. It is a trick question (I do not believe it is sincere) to get creationists to argue as if Darwinian evolution exists. (That is that the creation did not happen in six days, it is still ongoing and could continue millions of years into the future.) The question must be floating around on the internet at the moment - clever trick.

Comment: @Caleb This question wants a Catholic perspective. Your answer does not seem to be about a Catholic perspective, and it is not really citing the Vatican - the #1 authoritative source for all Catholics. Plus, you are using the ESV, a Reformed biblical translation of the Bible. Your answer just does not fit.

Comment: @Caleb In other words, I don't think your answer is representative of the Catholic voice.